# Modify values of in loop comprehension

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I am trying to add a string in cell if the length of that cell is more than one. I do it, so I have two groups of strings so in the whole column. That will help to create new columns by using the `str.split()`. Here is what I am doing:

```
[i if len(df.address.str.split())>1 else 'NA '+ i for i in df.address ]
```

here is sample of the data:

```
 store
 Le rateau , 37 rue Lagarde
 Cordonnerie Fabien, 42 penasse
 33 Charles de Gaule # I want to add to them ones So I can have store & address later
 LeClerc, 238 Le rabais


 ....
```

An output would like this:

```
 store
 Le rateau , 37 rue Lagarde
 Cordonnerie Fabien, 42 penasse
 'NA', 33 Charles de Gaule 
 LeClerc, 238 Le rabais
```

Comment: I would help to show an example of the expected output

Comment: @joao thanks. It has been updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try via boolean masking:

```
m=df['store'].str.split(',').str.len().eq(1)
#splitted the values by ',' and cheking if its length is 1
```

Finally pass that mask:

```
df.loc[m,'store']='NA, '+df.loc[m,'store']
#passing the boolean series(that we stored in m variable) in loc accessor and 
#modifying the values of store column where the above condition satisfying
```

output of `df`:

```
    store
0   Le rateau , 37 rue Lagarde
1   Cordonnerie Fabien, 42 penasse
2   NA, 33 Charles de Gaule
3   LeClerc, 238 Le rabais
```

Comment: Dabbas Fantastic. Great. I did not think of that. Surely because, I do not use it very often. Thanks again